# What symmetry statement can be made about the points $(a, b)$ and $(b, a)$?

Tags: coordinate-systems

The question is: if $a$ and $b$ are any two numbers, what symmetry statement can be made about the points $(a, b)$ and $(b, a)$?

I'm not sure whether this is a *symmetry* statements and whether it is the correct solution, but here's what I get

"the points $(a, b)$ and $(b, a)$ are symmetric with respect to the quarters if $a$ and $b$ have different signs"

Comment: They are symmetric with respect to the main diagonal

Comment: Ah, you were first :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are equidistant to the line $x=y$, i.e. they "mirror" each other in this line.